# Bulk rename worksheets to workbook (file) names in specfic folder

Tags: excel, directory, rename, worksheet, vba

I have 90 Excel sheets in a folder: each Excel file has a unique name (company number) and contains only *one* worksheet. However the sheet name is generically named to 'Sheet1' in all files. Is there a VBA code that can rename all these sheets in this folder to their respective file name, minus the '.xlsx'?

Basically I want to combine all sheets to one file (I already have that VBA script). However before I can proceed with that, I have to rename all excel sheet names to their unique identifier (which is the file name).

I already looked online, but didn't see this script yet or saw this script for similar other purposes. Thanks in advance!

Comment: VBA and VBScript are not the same, one is built into an application and the other standalone. You have also tagged batch-file, do you know what you want? because as it stands it appears that you're not looking for help with your code, but advice on how to go about the task. Unfortunately, StackOverflow is is a site dedicated to the former.

Comment: By 'batch' I mean just automatically perform something in bulk.

Well it's not the first time I have seen questions without any providing code. Never seen any comment on this. Anyways the question is solved, and I think it would be helpfull in the future of other users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution online, credits to user VoG on https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/660913-vba-code-bulk-rename-first-worksheet-dependent-workbook-name.html

This is the solution. Change ***MyFolder = "C:\example"*** to respective folder

```html
Sub RenSheets()
Dim MyFolder As String
Dim MyFile As String
Dim wbname As String
MyFolder = "C:\example"
MyFile = Dir(MyFolder & "\*.xls")
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Do While MyFile <> ""
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=MyFolder & "\" & MyFile
    With ActiveWorkbook
        wbname = Left(.Name, InStr(.Name, ".") - 1)
        .Sheets(1).Name = wbname
        .Close savechanges:=True
    End With
    MyFile = Dir
Loop
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: The problem with this code is if there is a full stop in the filename that is not the separator between the name and suffix, it will give you the wrong results.

Here is an example: `?Activeworkbook.name    
This.Is.My.Test.File.Name.xlsx    
?Left(Activeworkbook.Name, InStr(Activeworkbook.Name, ".") - 1)    
This
`

In this example I would say it would be better to split the Activeworkbook.name using "." then loop through the resulting array to ubound(arrayname)-1 joining as you go or use Join and take the left len of the string minus the len of the final element in the array

Comment: Although being that you are specifying `*.xls` you could simply do `wbname = Left(.Name, Len(.Name) - 4)` as we know with 100% confidence that there is 4 chars for the `.xls`

Comment: Ah I see your point. Fortunately I didn't have this issue as I don't have any additional dots in the filenames. Thanks for the insight

Comment: @DanDonoghue, doesn't VBA have method to get the base file name without the extension like Vbscript does instead of subtracting 4 from the end of the file name?

Comment: I thought it did but when I played around with it I couldn't find it :(.